# Generators with recursion, "decedents" of a list of lists

Tags: python, recursion, generator

Given a list of lists, L* = [L1,L2...Ln], let's say L*' is a child of L if to consecutive lists in L* are concatenated, like so: L' = [L1,L2... L(k-1), Lk+L(k+1), ... Ln]. If L*' is a child of L*, it is also a dependent of L*, and all children of L*' are also decedents of L*.

In Python, I tried to code up a generator which would provide all decedents, but my code just... skips it? I believe it was because I used generators wrong, because when I returned everything in a big list, everything worked, here are the two versions:

Defunct generator:

```
def gensuperlayers(layers,m=10):#m is max length of a layer, layers = [L1,L2...Ln]
    if len(layers) == 1:
        return layers
    for poss in gensuperlayers(layers[1:],m):
        yield [layers[0]]+poss
    if len(layers[0])+len(layers[1]) < m:
        if len(layers) == 2:
            return layers
        for poss in gensuperlayers([layers[0]+layers[1]]+layers[2:],m):
            yield poss
```

Recursive lists:

```
def gensuperlayers(layers,m=10):
    if len(layers) == 1:
        return [layers]
    returning = []
    for poss in gensuperlayers(layers[1:],m):
        returning.append([layers[0]]+poss)
    if len(layers[0])+len(layers[1]) < m:
        if len(layers) == 2:
            returning.append(layers)
        else:
            for poss in gensuperlayers(layers[2:],m):
                returning.append([layers[0]+layers[1]]+poss)
    return returning
```

Comment: You have both a `return` (with a value) and a `yield` in the same function, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: I used that as a lazy way to not do the rest of the function, but in hind sight I could've simply used ```else``` instead, I'll see if that works

Comment: well, that did it

Comment: Just change the test to `!= 2` and put the rest of the code inside that.

Comment: yeah I've fixed it now